# Tweepy - API.Search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to be able to run a search for keywords (`ContinuousDelivery` in this example) and have it return the date created, text and screen name of tweets containing the keyword and store it into a CSV which will ultimately be ported to a relational database.

1. I can get the created and text but not the screen name with code below.
2. I am also wondering how I can be sure I am getting all of the results pursuant to my request.

I have looked at Twitter API documentation and the `tweepy` GitHub but neither has got me far.

```
# --OAuth Headers omitted--

api = tweepy.API(auth)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('result17.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

 for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                q="ContinuousDelivery", 
                #since="2014-02-14", 
                #until="2014-02-15", 
                lang="en").items(5000000):
#Write a row to the csv file/ I use encode utf-8
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.screen_name])
print tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.screen_name
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Does tweet.author.screen_name or tweet.user.screen_name work?

Comment: @YuriSchimke yes it does. thanks yuri!

Comment: @hansolo - did you find you were getting 429 errors using this method of searching twitter?

Answer (score 1):

To get the author's screenname use tweet.author.screen_name.  The profile is it's own object inside the tweet.